# Get an Object of UserManager Class in Asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Services_Website.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Services_Website.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Services_Website.CustomFunctions
{
    public class CustomUserOperations: Controller
    {

        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public ApplicationUser GetCurrentUser()
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = User;
            _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>();
            var user =_userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

*** This is my Controller ***

I Just want to get an object of the UserManager Class But when I do it I am getting this ERROR

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'store' of 'UserManager.UserManager(IUserStore, IOptions, IPasswordHasher, IEnumerable>, IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger>)'    Services_Website    F:\webApplication\CoreApp\Services_Website\Services_Website\CustomFunctions\CustomUserOperations.cs 75      Active *

*What is the Error source

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use dependency injection to get an instance of `UserManager` class. Just add parameter to `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{}
```

and then in controller:

```
public class CustomUserOperations: Controller
{
     private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
     CustomUserOperations(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
     {
         _userManager = userManager;
     }

     public ApplicationUser GetCurrentUser()
     {
         ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = User;
         var user =_userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
         return user;
     }
}
```

You can read more about [dependency injection here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Identity like this for example:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

That will tell your app to populate the claims on the `ClaimsPrinciple`, add the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` to your DI pipeline, and configure your `ApplicationDbContext` as the persistence store.

Then you can inject `UserManager`/`RoleManager` into any constructor you need to using the DI pipeline like this:

```cs
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public CustomUserOperations(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity